# Weird issue with Zend_Framework bootstrap

Tags: zend-framework

I am trying to setup the Zend Framework on a windows machine and I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract' not found in C:\wwwroot \projects\relaunch\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\Bootstrap.php on line 36
```

My include path is:

```
C:\wwwroot\projects\relaunch\library;.;C:\php\pear;c:\php\includes
```

Comment: is that space supposed to be in your path (C:\wwwroot \project) in the error message or was that a typo?

Comment: Be prepared for more crazyness :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your autoloader is not working.  Does your autoloader setup look like this?

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$autoloader->registerNamespace('MyApp_');
$autoloader->setFallbackAutoloader(true);
```

I imagine your bootstrap specifically includes the Zend\Application\Bootstrap\Bootstrap.php file, but then things trip up on the autoload of the parent class.  (`Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap` doesn't specifically include its parent, which is unusual, but usually easily handled by autoloader.)